# C programming language, memory problems

Tags: c

I'm trying to read a file text(input.txt) which consists of multiple line like A B 120       C B 60...
Well, now I'm trying to transfer the names that may have been repeated more than once in that file into a double pointer where they should be shown only once. In my code below I get some of them but I also get a segmentation fault. I don't know what I am missing or what's wrong. Any little help of yours could help me very much.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   int i=1, state=0, k, dist;
int** myMat;
char *city1, *city2, **matnames;
FILE* p;
    city1 = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
    city2 = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
    matnames = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*));
    myMat = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*));               
p = fopen(argv[1],"r");
/************************************************************/
    matnames[0] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
    matnames[1] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
    matnames[2] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
    matnames[2] = NULL;
    fscanf(p, "%s %s %d", city1, city2, &dist);
        strcpy(matnames[0],city1);
        strcpy(matnames[1],city2);
/************************************************************/  
while( fscanf(p,"%s %s %d",city1,city2, &dist) != EOF){             
        for(k=0; matnames[k]!=NULL; k++){                   
            if( strcmp(matnames[k], city1) != 0){
                 state++;
                }               
        }       
        if(state  == k){
            matnames[k] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
            strcpy(matnames[k], city1);
            matnames[k+1] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
            matnames[k+1] = NULL;
            }
        state = 0;
        for(k=0; matnames[k] != NULL;k++){                  
                if( strcmp(matnames[k], city2) != 0){
                    state++;
                }               
        }
        if(state == k){
            matnames[k] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
            matnames[k+1] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
            strcpy(matnames[k], city2); 
            matnames[k+1] = NULL;   
            }
        state = 0;

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: After a quick look I see that `malloc(sizeof(char))` allocates memory for a __single__ char so your `fscanf` calls overflow `city1` and `city2`.

Comment: I also don't see any calls to `free()` or `fclose()`. You should practice better resource management to avoid leaking memory or file handles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
matnames = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

You allocated enough memory for just one `char*` here.

Then you are calling

```
matnames[1] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
```

whereas matnames  has space only for one `char*`, `matnames[1]` is trying to access space for a second `char *`.

What you need to do is

```
matnames = (char**) malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
```

where `n` is the number of elements you expect to store in `matnames[]`

Comment: oh thanks man.Thank you very much. It now worked. God bless you. I had hours trying to find my mistake..

Answer (score 1):

Among other things, you've allocated enough memory for `matnames` to store *one* `char *`, but you're storing three values in it. It also doesn't help that you malloc some memory for `matnames[2]` and then immediately overwrite the malloc'd pointer with `NULL` — but that's just a memory leak, since you don't actually try to store anything into `*(matnames[2])`. There may be other problems, but let's start with the most immediate one.

Answer (score 1):

You might also be interested in "strdup()":

- http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup

It combines "malloc()" and "strcpy()" into one operation - and saves you from worrying about whether or not you've "malloc'ed" the correct size.

Answer (score 1):

In C, the expression `sizeof(char)` will always return `1`.  This is by definition: `sizeof()` can work on many different kinds of computer, and not every one uses bytes.

So you are allocating only one byte for each name.  If the city names can be 20 characters long, use `malloc(21)` (don't forget to also have space for the terminating `'\0'` in the string).

For the `(char **)` pointer, you should figure out how many pointers you will need to store, and multiply by `sizeof(char *)`.  So, if you need to store 3 `char *` pointers, then use `malloc(3 * sizeof(char *))`.

Comment: If the city names can be 20 characters long he/she should `malloc(21)` to allow for the null terminator.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I swear I wouldn't make that mistake at work, but I'm pretty tired right now.  I'll edit the answer to make the point: don't forget the NUL.